# Email all values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, email

I am collecting information through a basic HTML form. Some of the fields are arrays indicated with `[]` after their name.

I have successfully written to a MySQL database and I am now trying to put the array values into a PHP-generated email. The email is being sent successfully with some of the variables printing, but none of the array values are coming through. How do I go about this?

`$name`, `$position` and `$email` are the values I am having issues with:

```
<?php     
$to = "myemail@email.com";
$subject = "Media Request";
$message = "A media credential request has been submitted for $outlet. The editor is $editor and their contact info is $Eemail and $phone.";
$message .= '<html><body>';
$message .= "<h2>Credential Request</h2>";
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr><td align=right><strong>Name:</strong> </td>
<td>" . strip_tags("$name") . "</td>
<td align=right><strong>Position:</strong> </td>
<td>" . strip_tags("$position") . "</td> 
<td align=right><strong>Email:</strong> </td>
<td>" . strip_tags("$email") . "</td></tr>";                
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= ("Here are the comments and special instructions: $notes ");
$from = "email@email.com";
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: should that be `$_POST['name']` ? whats the source of `$name`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have captured the form data in the variables you mentioned, you can use one of the following methods to output the array values:

**Loop through the elements**

```
foreach ($name as $name_field) {
    $message .= "Your text here. $name_field. More Text";
}
```

**Implode() and echo**

You can convert the entire array into a string in one line using [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/implode):

```
$message .= "Your text here." . implode(',', $name) . "More text here";
```

**Note:**

Verify that you have the expected data in `$name`, `$position` and `$email`. You can do this with `var_dump()`:

```
var_dump($name, $position, $email);
```